# Ionic 3 - Do providers persist over pages?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Scenario:

When a user verifies their mobile phone, they will call the Login() function of this auth provider. After immediatly logging in they are taken to a profile page which will call the getUser function. However, the variables user_id and user_token do not persist.

providers/Auth.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Api} from './api';
import {Settings} from './settings';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Storage} from "@ionic/storage";


@Injectable()
export class Auth {
    isLoggedIn: Boolean;
    user_id: String;
    user_token: String;

    constructor(public http: Http, public api: Api, public settings: Settings, public storage: Storage) {
    }

    login(user) {


        this.logout();


        this.storage.set('user_id', user.id);
        this.storage.set('user_jwt', user.jwt);

        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        this.user_id = user._id;
        this.user_token = user.jwt;


    }

    logout() {

        this.storage.remove('user_id');
        this.storage.remove('user_jwt');

        this.isLoggedIn = false;
        this.user_id = null;
        this.user_token = null;
    }

    isAuthenticated() {
        return this.isLoggedIn;
    }

    getUser() {

        console.log("UserID: " + this.user_id);
        console.log("UserToken: " + this.user_token);

        if (this.isAuthenticated()) {
            return {
                id: this.user_id,
                token: this.user_token,
            };
        }

    }

}
```

P.S i have added this provider in the app.module.ts providers [].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **doesn't persist** the data. So you must get the data through your `storage` module as shown below.

```
getUser() {
     // to get a key/value pair
      this.storage.get('user_id').then((val) => {
        console.log('Your user_id', val);
      });
}
```

Comment: But i am clearing the previous session, and setting a new one directly after. As you can see.You see directly below in login function i set this.user_id = user._id etc.

Comment: No, it won't work that way. Those are `promises`. So try without doing that and see the result.

Comment: Hi i removed the logout, but they are still undefined.

Comment: Then your problem is `user` object here `login(user) ` what was the value of it? You can easily debug this no?

Comment: Yes that value is fine. in login i added 2 console logs after setting the user and token and they return fine. Only when i call the getUser on a dif page there is a problem. I want to confirm providers can persist when moving between pages?

Comment: I gave the answer on my original post. You can see that. **NO**

Comment: Ok so it does not persist, the data that is what i asked, i wonder if there is a way to access the storage to return both userid and token at same time.

Comment: Yes, You can. You need to declare it as an `object` and then store it inside the `storage`.

Comment: When i access the auth provier on another page like this.         console.log(this.auth.getUser()); i still get undefined even when returning the storage.get

Comment: You cannot handle `promises` like that. You must wait till the promise `resolved`.

Comment: ok thanks i got it working now. finally, is it good practice to handle users in this session/storage?

Comment: Yes, It is a normal practice with Ionic. But you need to use `SQLite` plugin for more consistent storage on any device.

Comment: Ah okay, do you have any article or code sample i can see using SQLlite?

Comment: Doesent seem simple, if im getting a user object in storage to return the function isAuthenticated. Was hoping for something a little simple without the need for so many promises.

Comment: You just need to install SQLite. You can read it here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

Comment: Ok ty, i also changed this provider and added the storage.get in the constructor. This is possibly more cleaner now and it works. https://pastebin.com/HhscnY1g what do you think?

Comment: Yes, I cannot see any problem in that implementation.